# containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier for iPhone/iPad

Tags: ios, code-signing-entitlements

As suggested in link : [How containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier in NSFileManager works on iOS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21048742/1878280)
I was able to get two application access common location **/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/7.0.3/Containers/somegroupIDhere/** on simulator.

However when I try to run the application on device(iPhone/iPad) Im getting following error
[image]

Following is my entitlement file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>keychain-access-groups</key>
    <array>
        <string>teamIDHere.com.abc.pqr</string>
    </array>
    <key>Can be debugged</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.app-sandbox</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.application-groups</key>
    <array>
        <string>teamIDHere.com.abc.pqr</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: Did you enable Keychain-sharing when you created your profile from dev center?

Comment: Well I did not see any option to enable Keychain-Sharing for profile. It is available in capabilities but not in provisioning profile.